# android how to disable changing through apps

Tags: android, locking, administration

currently I am working on a parental control app and I want the child keep from removing the app. For this, I want to lock the device when the child wants to disable my app from device admins (in settings/security) and show an activity to enter the password. But after the activity is shown, I can still use the device by changing through apps (by double square button on the device, I don't know its name).

How can I lock the device such that the user only can see my password asking activity & can't do anything but either enter the password or cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the kiosk mode in android ?

please follow  [How to implement kiosk mode in android ?](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/)

here on Back / Home / Minimize button you can open your dialog for password and if password is true then `finish()` your current activity.

you can also use `KeyEvent` for that

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
     {
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
     }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

you can find  [all android keys here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)